# Make scrollspy spy on other tags than headers

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Just learning [html](/questions/tagged/html), [css](/questions/tagged/css) and [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and got this crazy idea of using the `<abbr>` tag in my code along with a `scrollspy.js` (from [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)) setup that spy on the viewed paragraphs and displays the definition of the abbreviations/acronym.

As I just learned the fundamental of [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) I want to know if that that possible by the script itself or does it need some modification (if so please post a code example, thx!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source of [scrollspy.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/scrollspy.js) you actually don't see any reference to headers.  It works by looking at the navigation links and corresponding elements for clues about the relationship between content elements and that navigation.  Here is how it looks in the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)

For nav

```
<a href="#fat">@fat</a>
```

For the section

```
<h4 id="fat">@fat</h4>
```

Now one thing to consider, `<h4>` elements are block level so they take up an entire row.  Inline elements can be on the same line, so it might be impossible to see which definition should be highlighted based on the visible section.  For what you are trying to do I think you need to create your own bit of JavaScript.

Here is one approach (though it will need some tweaking to work for your exact needs it supports inline abbr elements and even more than one definition per line per line) (and here is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/gL706v8g/))

Here is the JavaScript:

```
var mapTerms = function () {
    /*grab all of the <abbr>s with terms associated with them, they can move anytime the browser is resized*/
    var terms = [];
    $('abbr[data-term]').each(function () {
        var term = $(this);
        terms.push({
            term: term.data('term'),
            height: term.offset().top,
            visible: false,
            element: term
        });
    });
    return terms;
},
terms = [],
    /*Keep a globally accessible list*/
    $body = $('body'); /*need a reference to the body for performance*/

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    /*listen to the scroll event*/
    var height = $(document).scrollTop(),
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
        if (terms[i].visible) {
            if (terms[i].height < height || terms[i].height > (height + 50)) {
                terms[i].visible = false;
                terms[i].element.removeClass('defined');
                $('div[data-term=' + terms[i].term + ']').hide();
            }
        } else {
            if (terms[i].height > height && terms[i].height < (height + 50)) {
                terms[i].visible = true;
                terms[i].element.addClass('defined');
                $('div[data-term=' + terms[i].term + ']').show();
            }
        }
    }
}).on('resize', function () {
    /*listen to the resize event*/
    console.log('mapping...');
    terms = mapTerms();
}).trigger('resize').trigger('scroll');
```

And here is some CSS that hides and highlights the terms and their definitions (as well as keeps the definitions visible):

```
abbr.defined {
    background: red;
}
.definition {
    display: none;
}
#definitions {
    position: fixed;
}
```

The way it works is by looking for `<abbr>` that have a data element that points to a full definition like this:

```
<abbr data-term='blog' title='Webblog'>blog</abbr>
```

Each of these points to a div that holds a definition (stuffed in the sidebar at the bottom in the example)

```
<div class='definition' data-term='blog'>
  <h4>Blog</h4>

  <p>A blog (a truncation of the expression weblog) is a discussion or informational site published on the World Wide Web and consisting of discrete entries ("posts") typically displayed in reverse chronological order (the most recent post appears first).</p>
  <p><i>source <a href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blog'>Wikipedia</a></i></p>
</div>
```

Then as you resize the browser the `onResize` code builds a map of all of the `<abbr>` elements are, and as you scroll the `onScroll` code looks are your current position and tries to figure out if each term is visible (it is using a very simple definition of visible which is within the top 50 pixels of your browser).  In production you would probably want to test if it is between the scroll top and the window height, or account for things like the user scrolling down to read more of the definition but pushing the term off the screen.  It's a tricky thing to get 100% right, but this should get you further.

Comment: JS is quite new to me.. Any help building such JS script would be appreciated. Just something to get me started.

Comment: Just created an implementation (with demo) :) Kind of a fun problem.  Good luck